# XeLaTeX 2022 cannot show custom bold font while XeLaTeX 2014 works fine

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, overleaf

I am trying to use the same custom font after upgrading XeLaTeX from 2014 to 2022, however, the bold font no longer works while the regular and italic font still work. The following code reproduces the issue on Overleaf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{GoudyOldStyle}[ 
Path=font/,
Extension = .ttf,
BoldFont = *Bold,
ItalicFont = *Italic
]

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}
plain text\\
\textit{italic text}\\
\textbf{bold text}

\end{document}
```

With XeLaTeX 2014 (Overleaf Tex Live version = 2014 legacy) it works fine

[image: 2014]

However, with XeLaTeX 2022, the bold font no longer works (note that the plain and italic text are still in my custom font, but bold is in the default font)

[image: 2022]

Could you suggest what might be wrong here? Thank you!

Fonts
[image: fonts/]

I uploaded fonts to a temporary bin https://filebin.net/qftsxl6h9qlh13df

As suggested, I ran `pdffonts` on the pdf generated by 2022. The result is

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
GoudyOldStyle-Bold                   CID TrueType      Identity-H       no  no  yes     19  0
AAMNXV+Goudy-Old-Style-Normal        CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     21  0
BWBBUJ+GoudyOldStyleT-Italic         CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     23  0
```

Similarly, with 2014

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
IJMMCT+GoudyOldStyle-Bold            CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     21  0
KOGHSG+Goudy-Old-Style-Normal        CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     23  0
XHHQDW+GoudyOldStyleT-Italic         CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     25  0
```

Comment: Could you clarify? I see a bold font in both images, and it's even bolder in the second example (which I assume is 2022).

Comment: @Miyase the first bold font is the "correct" custom font that I intended to use. The second bold font is just the default font (times new roman or something). I hope this is clear regarding the issue here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle good to know. may I ask why? (overleaf autogenerated it)

Comment: @Mr.cysl Both `inputenc` and `fontenc` are obsolete when using LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX, since those compilers natively support UTF8.

Comment: @Mr.cysl I understand your problem better now. You should explain this in your original post.

Comment: @Miyase I thought `\setmainfont` is from `fontspec`? Could you suggest a better alternative here? Thanks.

Comment: @Miyase I updated the original post :)

Comment: @Mr.cysl I said `fontenc` is obsolete, not `fontspec`.

Comment: Good to know, folks. I verified that inputenc doesn't have an impact of the problem described. Do any of you know how I could make my custom bold font work with latest XeLaTeX? Let me know if you need the font files to reproduce.

Comment: Can you confirm the font file names in `./font`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle added a screenshot to show. BTW I only changed the version of TeX Live without touching any files, so filename should be right.

Comment: yes but the filenames allows others to test

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. I also updated the font files to a temporary bin if you wanna try it out https://filebin.net/qftsxl6h9qlh13df

Comment: @Mr.cysl no I will not use commercial fonts unpaid.  Does `BoldFont = GoudyOldStyleBold.ttf` work (ie not using `*` or default extension)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it doesn't. Still the same.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In case the log helps: XeLaTeX 2014 (https://pastebin.com/571bps6r) XeLaTeX 2022 (https://pastebin.com/cuLDbR6k)

Comment: hmm 2022 one claims `'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"[font/GoudyOldStyleBold.ttf]/OT:language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;"` so bold should be set up (as b not bx) although a substitution should work but does `\fontseries{b}\selectfont abc` do the right thing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140289/discussion-between-mr-cysl-and-david-carlisle).

Comment: What fonts does running `pdffonts` on the output file say are being used?

Comment: @Davislor How should I run it?

Comment: @Mr.cysl From the command line. Either compile your document to PDF locally or download the PDF from Overleaf.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks. Added the printout above

Comment: @Mr.cysl Interesting; the compiler seems to have found a different `GoudyOldStyleBold`. What does the `.log` file show for the pathname?

Comment: @Davislor it seems that the path is correct. see https://pastebin.com/p1FWEjL5

Comment: @Mr.cysl Are you sure that the 2014 version is choosing the correct font and scaling correctly? They’re clearly finding two completely different fonts, where the lowercase d is the most distinct.

Comment: @Davislor How shall I verify? The pdf output with 2014 looks correct, while with 2022 looks incorrect.

Comment: So I think there is no issue with 2014.

Comment: @Mr.cysl It “looks correct,” but are you certain that the font it is using is actually the one in your subdirectory? And that it is the same file in both cases?

Comment: @Davislor Yes. There is only one set of font in the dir and I have been using it for a long while, so could easily tell the difference. And yes, everything is the same except I changed Tex Live version from 2014 to a more recent version like 2021 or 2022.

Comment: You could tell I have been using it for long as I was using the 2014 xelatex before :)

Comment: The issue might be scaling. (With the ascender of the d possibly getting clipped?)  Does adding `BoldFeatures={Scale=1.0},` help? Or `{Scale=MatchLowercase}`?

Comment: Or is there some kind of variable font parameter here that `fontspec` wasn’t detecting in 2014, but is setting to an incorrect default today?

Comment: @Davislor Tried but neither works. I also tried to change the scaling factor to 1.5 and I could see the bold font size increases, though the font is still incorrect.

Comment: well the font is not embedded. But you will have to run `xelatex --output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv" main` to get some debug info. Add als `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` to the document. Without it it is impossible to help.